# Hibernate: how to call a stored function returning a varchar?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a legacy stored function in an Oracle9i DB from Java using Hibernate. The function is declared like this:

```
create or replace FUNCTION Transferlocation_Fix (mnemonic_code IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
```

After several failed tries and extensive googling, I found [this thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=976887&view=previous) on the Hibernate forums which suggested a mapping like this:

```
<sql-query name="TransferLocationFix" callable="true">
    <return-scalar column="retVal" type="string"/>
    select Transferlocation_Fix(:mnemonic) as retVal from dual
</sql-query>
```

My code to execute it is

```
    Query query = session.getNamedQuery("TransferLocationFix");
    query.setParameter("mnemonic", "FC3");
    String result = (String) query.uniqueResult();
```

and the resulting log is

```
DEBUG (org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher:366) -  - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG (org.hibernate.SQL:401) -  - select Transferlocation_Fix(?) as retVal from dual
TRACE (org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher:484) -  - preparing statement
TRACE (org.hibernate.type.StringType:133) -  - binding 'FC3' to parameter: 2
TRACE (org.hibernate.type.StringType:133) -  - binding 'FC3' to parameter: 2

java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTCAdapter.newTTCType(TTCAdapter.java:300)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTCAdapter.createNonPlsqlTTCColumnArray(TTCAdapter.java:270)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTCAdapter.createNonPlsqlTTCDataSet(TTCAdapter.java:231)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1924)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteDescribe(TTC7Protocol.java:850)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteQuery(OracleStatement.java:2599)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:2963)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:658)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:736)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyCallableStatement.execute(NewProxyCallableStatement.java:3044)
at org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect.getResultSet(Oracle8iDialect.java:379)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:193)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1784)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:811)
at com.my.project.SomeClass.method(SomeClass.java:202)
...
```

Any clues what am I doing wrong? Or any better ways to call this stored function?

---

**Update:** upon trying @axtavt's suggestion, I get the following error:

```
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query
```

The function indeed does extensive inserts/updates, so I guess the only way to run it would be using the stored procedure syntax. I just have no clue how to map the return value:

```
<sql-query name="TransferLocationFix" callable="true">
    <return-scalar column="???" type="string"/>
    { ? = call Transferlocation_Fix(:mnemonic) }
</sql-query>
```

What should be the `column`? I will try an empty value...

---

**Update2:** that failed as well, with an SQL Grammar Exception... So I tried the JDBC way as suggested by Pascal, and it seems to work! I added the code in an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure and I didn't test it but according to Hibernate's documentation:

> ### [16.2.2. Using stored procedures for querying](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query)
>
> Hibernate3 provides support for
>   queries via stored procedures and
>   functions. Most of the following
>   documentation is equivalent for both.
>   **The stored procedure/function must return a resultset as the first
>   out-parameter to be able to work with
>   Hibernate**. An example of such a
>   stored function in Oracle 9 and higher
>   is as follows:
>
> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selectAllEmployments
>     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
> AS
>     st_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
> BEGIN
>     OPEN st_cursor FOR
>  SELECT EMPLOYEE, EMPLOYER,
>  STARTDATE, ENDDATE,
>  REGIONCODE, EID, VALUE, CURRENCY
>  FROM EMPLOYMENT;
>       RETURN  st_cursor;
>  END;
> ```
>
> To use this query in Hibernate you
>   need to map it via a named query.
>
> ```
> <sql-query name="selectAllEmployees_SP" callable="true">
>     <return alias="emp" class="Employment">
>         <return-property name="employee" column="EMPLOYEE"/>
>         <return-property name="employer" column="EMPLOYER"/>
>         <return-property name="startDate" column="STARTDATE"/>
>         <return-property name="endDate" column="ENDDATE"/>
>         <return-property name="regionCode" column="REGIONCODE"/>
>         <return-property name="id" column="EID"/>
>         <return-property name="salary">
>             <return-column name="VALUE"/>
>             <return-column name="CURRENCY"/>
>         </return-property>
>     </return>
>     { ? = call selectAllEmployments() }
> </sql-query>
> ```
>
> Stored procedures currently only
>   return scalars and entities.
>   `<return-join>` and
>   `<load-collection>` are not supported.
>
> #### [16.2.2.1. Rules/limitations for using stored procedures](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-limits-storedprocedures)
>
> You cannot use stored procedures with
>   Hibernate unless you follow some
>   procedure/function rules. **If they do
>   not follow those rules they are not
>   usable with Hibernate. If you still
>   want to use these procedures you have
>   to execute them via
>   `session.connection()`**. The rules are
>   different for each database, since
>   database vendors have different stored
>   procedure semantics/syntax.
>
> Stored procedure queries cannot be
>   paged with
>   `setFirstResult()/setMaxResults()`.
>
> The recommended call form is standard
>   SQL92: `{ ? = call
>   functionName(<parameters>) }` or `{ ?
>   = call procedureName(<parameters>}`. Native call syntax is not supported.
>
> For Oracle the following rules apply:
>
> - **A function must return a result set. The first parameter of a
>     procedure must be an OUT that returns
>     a result set. This is done by using a
>     SYS_REFCURSOR type in Oracle 9 or
>     10.** In Oracle you need to define a REF CURSOR type. See Oracle literature
>     for further information.
>
> ...

As I said, I'm not sure but my understanding is that you'll have to use `session.getConnection()` here.

Comment: I read that too, but I am not sure either, since in a different part of the book (ch 8.2.2) there is a section about calling stored functions (however, there is no straightforward example :-( ). And the forum thread I found suggests that it is indeed possible using `getNamedQuery()`...

Comment: @Péter Indeed, and axtavt's answer goes in the same direction. I'm eager to see if it works.

Comment: FYI, in the end it turned out the Hibernate documentation is right in this case, so I had to use JDBC.

Answer (score 11):

For further reference, here is my final solution:

```
CallableStatement statement = session.connection().prepareCall(
        "{ ? = call Transferlocation_Fix(?) }");
statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
statement.setString(2, "FC3");
statement.execute();
String result = statement.getString(1);
```

Comment: But how to do it with javax.persistence.EntityManager ..?

Comment: @kanagavelu-sugumar      =Did you get the answere plese reply

Answer (score 2):

`callable = true` is for calling stored procedures with `{? = call ...()}` syntax. Oracle's `select ... from dual` syntax is a normal query, so you don't need `callable = true`:

```
<sql-query name="TransferLocationFix"> 
    <return-scalar column="retVal" type="string"/> 
    select Transferlocation_Fix(:mnemonic) as retVal from dual 
</sql-query>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a similar question/problem and I've come to realize the changes should be done on the sql part as hibernate works only with cursor returns. I've described everything here: http://www.len.ro/2011/10/call-oracle-procedure-from-hibernate/