# Retrieve multiple rows with column names from PostgreSQL function using Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

There is `Postgresql` function which returns multiple rows using `return table(...)` construction:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo (
  p1 bigint,
  p2 bigint,
  p3 bigint)
  RETURNS table(v1 varchar, v2 bigint, ...)
...
```

I'm trying execute it via Hibernate, using `ProcedureCall` class:

```
ProcedureCall fooCall = getSession().createStoredProcedureCall("foo");
fooCall.registerParameter(1, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(p1);
fooCall.registerParameter(2, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(p2);
fooCall.registerParameter(3, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(p3);

ProcedureOutputs outputs = fooCall .getOutputs();
Object result = ((ResultSetOutput)outputs.getCurrent()).getResultList();
```

The problem is that `result` appears to be essentially `List` of `Object` arrays (`List<Object[]>`), which contain only values without names of columns. But I strongly need also columns names as they defined in stored procedure (`v1`, `v2` - is just a samples). Is any way to retrieve them from result of stored procedure call?

Comment: In same PHP code result contains map (column key -> value), so it should be theoretically possible to do

Comment: Does your procedure return column names when used from a DB client such as SQLSquirrel etc? BTW, I see that you didn't define the return type (you need to define the out (return ) parameter type so you will basically have 4 params, not 3. It's possible that you will have to define a custom type in PostgreSQL and rewrite your function to return that custom type (instead of a table) because not all native database types are represantable in Java (JDBC).

Comment: There's some more information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942977/hibernate-how-to-call-a-stored-function-returning-a-varchar